# Universal Generalization properties

Tags: logic

So I am looking for a proof (it is probably simple) to :

$ \vdash  (\forall x)A \rightarrow A$

Any help would be appreciate !!

Comment: Check [This](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/cst.pdf) if you need some theory example. All that you need is explained around page 50. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Most systems of first-order logic have a universal quantifier instantiation rule of the form:

> from $\forall xA$ infer $A[x/t]$,

where  $A[x/t]$ is the result of substituting the term $t$ for all free occurrences of $x$ in $A$. Now take the particular case where the term we substitute for $x$ is ... $x$! Then, since $A[x/x]$ is trivially $A$,  we have as a special case

> from $\forall xA$ infer $A$.

Now use the deduction theorem or conditional proof to get as a theorem

> $\forall xA \to A$.

Fine print: in some syntaxes, where free variables (parameters) are typographically distinguished from bound variables, and where empty quantifiers which bind no variable are not allowed, then you won't get theorems of exactly this form (where '$A$' is exactly replaced by the same wff both times).